# How to press ImageView to the borders

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, imageview, android-imageview

I have a problem. I have an ImageView in layout with different size. I want to set that ImageView to the bottom of the screen. That Picture must press to bottom / right / left borders without space. But in my case in some devices i have space between picture and border(left|right). Whats the reason?! Is it because of size of the picture or incorrect code? How to make it equal in all devices?!

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/man"
    android:id="@+id/man"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the following attribute to your `ImageView`:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

`ScaleType` specifies how you want your image to behave with different scales, and here we forced it to occupy the full Width and Height specified for it no matter it's size.

Answer (score 0):

Put the imageview inside a relative layout with width of "**match_parent**" and height of "**match_parent**", 
and add the following attribute to your **imageView** : `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/man"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:id="@+id/man"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```